# Microsoft SSO without Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

Is it possible to use Microsoft SSO without using Azure in any way? I've tried looking into ways of avoiding it but everything I find seems to go back to AD.

The reason I want to try and avoid using AD is because I'm currently not able to access it but would like to build something using it in the meanwhile.

Comment: What do you mean by `Microsoft SSO` in the first place? Active Directory isn't Azure, it's your local Windows domain. All applications on Windows run under account of the user that executes them, removing the need to specify the credentials every time you use them. When an application connects to SQL Server it can do so as the current user

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to use. You can use SSO with azure active directory.